# How to resave images existing on disc in DM 3.4 (Force a replacement.)

Tags: save, dm-script

Try to do some image edit (add text and scale bar) and then automatically save/replace the original image, the codes work well with DM 2.0 and previous verison, but it does not work with 3.4 and 3.0, it shows " the process can not access the file because it is being used by another process". Is there any other way to do this with 3.4 and 3.0? thx

```
    image front:=getfrontimage()        
    string imgname=getname(front)
    string handler = "Gatan 3 Format"
        ImageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()     
    string thispath=pathconcatenate(currentdirectory, imgname)      
    doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( handler, thispath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not save a file to a file-name of a currently opened file. Instead, you want to "re-save" your opened file. The easiest way to do that would be

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
img *= -1   // Just something to modify the image
img.Save()
```

If you want to do the same with an ImageDocument instead, it would be

```
imageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSave(1)
```

> The parameter in the command can either be:
>
> - 0 = Always save, never prompt 
>   <sup>(Use linked location or folder of DigitalMicrograph.exe if not linked.)</sup>
> - 1 = Save without prompting, if already linked to file, else prompt
> - 2 = Always prompt

The following commands can also be useful when working with files and imageDocuments:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()

Result( "\n Image ["+img.ImageGetLabel()+"] " )
if ( doc.ImageDocumentIsLinkedToFile() )
    Result( "currenlty linked to:" + doc.ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile() )
else
    Result( "not linked to a file." )
```